# Join in Linq returns on matching records

Tags: linq

Hi I am having two tables Country and city , country(id,Name) ,city(id,Country_id,City_name) When I am having Index action method as below , If I have 4 rows in country and there are two associated rows in cities then it only shows two rows on Country index table I mean only matched records
below is controller code I need to show all Country list even though there is any assocaited city in city table or now

```
var test1 = (from c in db.Cities
                   join cc in db.Countries
                       on c.Country_Id equals cc.Id into u 
                       from cc1 in u.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   select new
                   {
                     Id = c.Id,
                     Name = c.Name,
                     Country_Id = c.Country.CountryName,
                     Code = c.Code,
                     IsActive = c.IsActive,

                     // IsActive = g.IsActive,
                     Date_Created = c.Date_Created,
                     Date_Modified = c.Date_Modified,
                     Latitude = c.Latitude,
                     Longitude = c.Longitude,


                   }).ToList();
      return Json(new { data = test1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Your left hand join is backwards - you are showing all `Cities` even if they have no `Countries`. Also, your answer doesn't use `cc1` so why are you doing the `join`? If you are using EF (e.g. `c.Country.CountryName`) then you don't need the join. You are starting with the wrong table.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?